# Solr HTTP error on server, HTTP request failed

Tags: ubuntu, solr, docker-compose

Search stopped working, in the logs on the server this is:

```php
Request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Solarium\Exception\HttpException:
"Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Failed to connect to solr port 8983:
Connection refused" at
/var/www/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php
line 195 {"exception":"[object] (Solarium\\Exception\\HttpException(code: 0): 
Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Failed to connect to solr port 8983:
Connection refused at 
/var/www/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php:195)"} []
```

Any guesses about what this is connected with are welcome.

docker-compose.yml:

```
solr:
        image: solr:latest
        env_file: .env
        ports:
            - 8983:8983
        volumes:
            - solr_volume:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
        entrypoint:
            - docker-entrypoint.sh
            - solr-precreate
            - ${SOLR_CORE}
```

.env:

```
# Solr
SOLR_HOST=solr
SOLR_PORT=8983
SOLR_PATH=/solr/
SOLR_CORE=election
```

[docker container running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSHkq.png)

Comment: Is Solr running?

Comment: "Failed to connect" indicates that there is nothing listening on that ip:port combination. If solr is on a different server, it may just be listening to connections from localhost (or it isn't running). If it's on the same server, it doesn't seem to be running.

Comment: solr is in a docker container and it works, at least this configuration worked for the past hosting provider. Added a screenshot of a running container and a solr configuration to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr in the docker container crashed with error 400, which caused it to not respond to external requests. Rebuilding the container solved this problem.